# SharePoint Excel Calculated formula for Column

Tags: sharepoint, formula, calculated-columns, sharepoint-2016

I have calculated field in my SharePoint 2016 on premises list, which checks for four 4 columns and update the calculated column based on the result, I have used this formula but its showing syntax error.

```
=IF(Column 4=ISBLANK,IF(Column 3=ISBLANK,IF(Column 2 =ISBLANK,IF(Column 1=ISBLANK,E2,Column 1),Column 2 ),Column 3),Column 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ISBLANK(Field)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-f2eb6d53-1c84-49c4-9db9-83c94d20200e)

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Column 4]),IF(ISBLANK([Column 3]),IF(ISBLANK([Column 2]),IF(ISBLANK([Column 1]),"E2",[Column 1]),[Column 2]),[Column 3]),[Column 4])
```